# VUE, Can't use selected option value in a select component

Tags: vue.js, select, vue-component, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

Im trying to use a selected option value. Can't show the value or save it.

This is my child component
`

```
<script>
export default {
  props: {
    options : {
      type:Array,
    },
    selectOpt:undefined,
  }
  emits : ['input','change','option:selected']
}
</script>

<template>
<div>
  <h1>
    Hi, I'm a component
  </h1>
<select
        v-model="selectOpt"
        @change="$emit('input', event.target.value)">
  <option v-for="option in options"
          :key="option"
          >{{option}}</option>
</select>
</div>
</template>
```

`
This is my parent

`

```
<script >
  import Comp from './Comp.vue'
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      options : [1,2,3,4,5,6],
      optSelected : undefined,
    }
  },
  components: {
    Comp
  }
}
</script>

<template>
  <Comp v-model="optSelected" :options="options"></Comp>
  <p>
    --->{{optSelected}}
  </p>
</template>
```

`

I tried changin the 'input' event and 'change' event. not sure what im doing wrong.
i've found a solution that requires a vue-select library that i prefer not to use.

Comment: you don't seem to understand the concept of emits. To simplify it, when you execute an `emit` in `Child`, the parent receives it as an event, similar to `@click` or `@mouseover` etc. Currently you don't even have the event on the parent to receive the data.

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple detail: in vue 3, you need to use `update:modelValue` in order to change the `v-model` in parent component. (Reference: https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/v-model.html)

And another thing: you souldn't use the prop as a `v-model` to prevent side effects in your application. You can read more about it here: https://eslint.vuejs.org/rules/no-mutating-props.html

Hope it helps:

```
<script>
export default {
  props: {
    options: {
      type: Array
    },
    modelValue: undefined
  },
  emits: ['update:modelValue'],
  watch: {
    innerValue(newValue) {
      this.$emit('update:modelValue', newValue)
    },
    modelValue(newValue) {
      this.innerValue = newValue;
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      innerValue: this.modelValue
    };
  }
};
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <h1>Hi, I'm a component</h1>
    <select v-model="innerValue">
      <option v-for="option in options" :key="option">
        {{ option }}
      </option>
    </select>
  </div>
</template>
```

---

[**Edit**] Using Fallthrough Attribute:

You can use the `v-bind="$atrrs"`:

```
<script>
export default {
  props: {
    options: {
      type: Array
    },
  },
};
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <h1>Hi, I'm a component</h1>
    <select v-bind="$attrs">
      <option v-for="option in options" :key="option">
        {{ option }}
      </option>
    </select>
  </div>
</template>
```

*Read more: https://vuejs.org/guide/components/attrs.html#attribute-inheritance-on-multiple-root-nodes*

Comment: Thank you, it is really helpful. 
Is there an option to do the same without "watch"?
i've been trying but cant do it niether.

Comment: @AntonioJ I have edited the answer in order to accomplish it without `watch` property